# Chrome Equivalent of %s address bar trick in Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, shortcuts, url, address-bar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a Google Chrome extension that acts like Firefox’s keyword quicksearch bookmarks?](https://superuser.com/questions/164489/is-there-a-google-chrome-extension-that-acts-like-firefoxs-keyword-quicksearch)

I was curious if there was an equivalent technique in Chrome to do address bar param string replacement like you can do in Firefox. If you create a bookmark and put a %s in the bookmark URL/address part, and set a keyword for the bookmark, you can do things like

```
URL: http://php.net/%s
Keyword: php

Type in browser: php fopen
End up at: http://php.net/fopen
```

Is this making its way into Chrome or is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 6):

You can edit your search engines list, and add URLs with keywords there.

Right click in the address bar to find the "edit search engines" option.

Comment: More info: http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95653