# Chrome: automatically redirect me to highest ranking search result, like Firefox does

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, address-bar

How to emulate the Firefox (I'm using v3.6) address bar search redirection in Google Chrome?

For example, if I type...

> imdb moon

...to the address bar and press Return in Firefox then it redirects me straight to http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1182345/ (and I've not visited the page before)

When I try this is Chrome then I just get the google search page http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=imdb+moon

So seems like Firefox redirects automatically to the highest ranking search result URL - is there a setting or add-on for Chrome to achieve the same behaviour?

Comment: Settings -> Search Engine -> Manage Search engines as described on https://superuser.com/questions/164489/is-there-a-google-chrome-extension-that-acts-like-firefoxs-keyword-quicksearch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set Google "I'm feeling lucky" as your default search provider. Instructions on [this page](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=3c0fcd06f767195c&hl=en):

> 1. Right-click the address bar and click on "Edit search engines...".
> 2. Click the Add button
> 3. Where it asks for a name type Google - I'm Feeling Lucky!
> 4. Where it ask for a keyword type im
> 5. Where it asks for a URL paste http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=navclient&gfns=1&q=%s
> 6. Click Ok to save your settings and exit the dialog box
> 7. Now click the Make Default button
> 8. Click the Close button at the bottom
> 9. Type in keywords in the address bar that describe the site you want like
>      Caterpillar for http://www.cat.com/